# CORS request: how to read server response if status is 0

Tags: javascript, cors

I'm performing a request via Javascript to a server using the following code:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
                xhr.open(method, url, true);
            } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url);
            } else {
                xhr = null;
            }
            return xhr;
        }
        var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://remoteurltobecalled");
        if (request) {
            request.onload = function () {
                if (request.readyState == request.DONE) {
                    if (request.status == 200) {
                        var text = request.responseText;
                        alert(text);
                    }
                } 
            }

            request.onerror = function () {
                alert('status:'+request.status);
                alert('statusText: '+request.statusText);
                alert('responseText: ' + request.responseText);
                alert('responseBody: ' + request.responseBody);
                alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
            };

            var response=request.send();
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Using Fiddler i can see that the response from the server is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 21 Jun 2017 09:20:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9A78296BD30D8AA45C1B4DF467118309; Path=/PATHREQUESTED
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 19982
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

And then there's the body of the response.

Anyway, the response in the javascript code is an error, with  status 0 and responseText and responseBody are empty. How could i get the full response provided by the server? is it a CORS issue?

Comment: No way if the remote resource doesn't support CORS. Try reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access) before asking such questions.

Comment: You are right: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header must be included in all valid CORS responses; omitting the header will cause the CORS request to fail. I would have expected therefore an error as response from the server, instead the response provided is 200 OK and the full response. Maybe i'm misleading this part.

Comment: _I would have expected therefore an error as response from the server._ That's wrong. Server **cannot** respond with error due to CORS issue. CORS is solely client's (browser's) responsibility. Server doesn't care about CORS except passing respective headers.